# Complexity of the program that finds number of products for given n

Tags: c++, for-loop, time-complexity

I have the code for finding the number of products for a given number n. I think that complexity is sqrt(n^3), but some of them think that it is n^2. Here is the code:

```
int f(int n)
{
    int i,j,k,p,r=0;
    k=sqrt(n);
    p=n/2;
    for (i=2; i<=p; i++)
        for(j=2; j<=k; j++)
            if(i*j==n)
                r++;
    return r;           
}
```

The reasoning behind my logic is next:

T=C1+(n/2-1)C2+(n/2-1)(sqrt(n)-1)C3

but I'm not completely sure

Comment: is this a typo `for(j=2; i<=k; j++)`  ? this loop will never terminate making the complexity `O(inf)` :P

Comment: Yeah it is a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Assuming the inner loop is meant to say `j<=k` rather than `i<=k`.*)

Your logic and answer are both correct (in the [big-Oh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) sense).

Another way to look at this is that the outer loop is `O(n/2)` (which is the same as `O(n)`) and the inner loop is `O(sqrt(n))`.  Multiplying the two gives `O(n*sqrt(n))`, which is algebraically equivalent to `O(sqrt(n^3))`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets refactor the code a bit. First, some density:

```
int f(int n)
{
    int r=0;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i=2; i<= n/2; i++)
        for(int j=2; j<=sqrt(n); j++) {
            if(i*j==n) r++;
            ++counter;
        }
    return r;           
}
```

I already introduced a counter and now we will move that counter up out of the loops:

```
int f(int n)
{
    int r=0;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i=2; i<= n/2; i++)
        counter += (sqrt(n) - 1);
        for(int j=2; j<=sqrt(n); j++) {
            if(i*j==n) r++;
        }
    return r;           
}
```

one more step:

```
int f(int n)
{
    int r=0;
    int counter = 0;
    counter += (n/2 - 1) * (sqrt(n) -1);
    for (int i=2; i<= n/2; i++)
        for(int j=2; j<=sqrt(n); j++) {
            if(i*j==n) r++;
        }
    return r;           
}
```

Conclusion: Your reasoning is correct. Them probably didnt realize that you only have to consider factors up to `sqrt(n)` which would leave you with worse complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of this code is O(Nsqrt(N)), because your first loop has `N/2` steps, and your second loop has `sqrt(N)` steps, multiply those, and you'll get `N/2*sqrt(N)`, hence the O(NsqrtN).

Comment: the outer loop goes till `n/2` not `sqrt(n)`

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 yeah, sorry.

Comment: just in case... `n * sqrt(n) == sqrt( n^3)`

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 no argument here =)